# How to handle file in Whoosh?

Tags: python, python-2.7, whoosh

In the adventure to build a search engine, I started with Whoosh. The tutorial and web based materials are fine. Stackoverflow also has sizable question and answers. The initial experiments seem going fine. But I want to handle files located in various parts of my machine. I found "from whoosh.filedb.filestore import FileStorage", but I am looking for a simple example to start with. 
I tried something as below, it may be giving some result but is it going okay?
If any one may please see and correct if required?

```
>>> txt_file1=open("/python27/whooshtext1.txt","r").read()
>>> txt_file2=open("/python27/whooshtext3.txt","r").read()
>>> writer.add_document(title=u"First document", path= unicode("indexdir"+os.sep+"a"),content=u"txt_file1")
>>> writer.add_document(title=u"Second document", path= unicode("indexdir"+os.sep+"b"),content=u"txt_file2")
>>> writer.commit()
>>> with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse("flood")
        results = searcher.search(query)
        print results
        for result in results:
        print result


<Top 0 Results for Term('content', u'flood') runtime=0.000124042337439>
>>>
```

Comment: Please consider to mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the content of the text files not their names in `writer.add_document`: `content=txt_file1.read()`  instead of `content=u"txt_file1"`. The same for the second file.

Be sure that the word "flood" exists inside one of the files.